# Missing deployment tile from Api App blade in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, kudu, azure-git-deployment

I'm in the process of evaluating App Service and in particular Api apps and logic apps. I want to be able to make use of git deploy for an Api app instance.

This article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/ mentions that even though it is based on web apps, you can apply the same processes to api apps, however, when I attempted to follow the tutorial using an api app instance, I was unable to see the "deployment" tile on the api app blade in the azure portal. I was able to complete the tutorial for the web app instance.

*Does anyone know why I wouldn't be able to see the deployment tile for an api app blade?*

I want to use the api app so I can make full use of swagger and the logic app service.

**Edit**
Thinking about it, do I even *need* to use an api app or could I get away with using a web app (with swagger meta data) for connecting to logic apps?

**Update**
Found it - see my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it and it's not a bug. I was being (a bit) dumb. Following [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-nodejs-api-app/), I discovered that I needed to click on the `Api app host` section and then `all settings` then `continuous deployment`.

This is, imho, a poor UX decision here, given the blade looks exactly the same as others that *do* have the deployment tile, but at least I can set up git deploy for my api apps now.

Answer (score 0):

@Simon

This may be a bug - I will poke the Azure Team for it asking that. Even though, WebApp, APIApp and MobileApp are EXACTLY the same service, only changing name. So, if you can see deployment tile for one of them, you should be able to see all others then.

BUT, there is a "invisible business link" around them that make all things working. When you work with Logic Apps, it will search for custom API Apps at - guess what! - you API App list. So, you can host a API application at WebApp, but probably the Logic App will not go for it by default.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I thought that might be the case re logic apps and api apps. Is there somewhere I can track the status of this (assuming it *is* a bug)

Comment: Try via Azure SDK, or [API REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460808.aspx).